# Swift - Scale UIWebView to size of content

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

So, I have a subclass of **UIWebView** and in this **UIWebView** I will be displaying Mathematical Expressions using **MathJax** in Swift. What I want to do, is to use the WebView like a **UILabel** so I disable *userInteraction* and *scrolling*. I found this :

```
lview.loadLatexString(latexString: "Hello !")
lview.frame.size.height = 1
lview.frame.size = lview.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
```

But that doesn't work. I have **this**:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And I want **this**:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I hope this clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for disabling the scroll of `webview` and `UserInteraction`

```
 myWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
   myWebView.isUserInteractionEnabled  = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with UITextView.

make scroll and user intrection disable, textview will resize according content. take sure you give proper constraint

```
let theString : String = "</p><img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/655066410087940096/QSUlrrlm.png' width=100 height=100 /><h2>Subheader</h2>"

let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: theString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!,options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],  documentAttributes: nil)

textview.attributedText =  theAttributedString
```